# Twilio CLI won't login even though I've set environment variables

Tags: twilio

On Mac OS in the terminal, when I type in twilio login I get:

```
 » Installing keytar ...
 » Secure credential storage failed to load.

Alternatively, twilio-cli can use credentials stored in environment variables:

# OPTION 1 (recommended)
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = your Account SID from twil.io/console
TWILIO_API_KEY = an API Key created at twil.io/get-api-key
TWILIO_API_SECRET = the secret for the API Key

# OPTION 2
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = your Account SID from twil.io/console
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = your Auth Token from twil.io/console

Once these environment variables are set, a twilio-cli profile is not required to move forward with installation.
```

However, I did try to set the environment variables by typing the statements below and it still didn't work (of course I replaced the strings with the actual values):

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="abcd"
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN="efgh"
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @mikemaccana Customer support emailed me and said that this was likely a bug with their CLI. The CLI uses ngrok under the hood so I just ended up using ngrok.

Comment: Almost 4 years later and I'm here because the CLI apparently still can't resolve credentials from ENV vars. That's reassuring.